# undefined variable when use routes/api laravel

Tags: laravel, query-builder

i get an error `undefinde variable: sequence_id` when getting data from database using query builder in my controllers when using routes api.php, **but when using web.php routes its working fine**. and its seem the query doesnt have result when using api.php.

```
$sequence = DB::connection('pgsql2')
                ->table('ad_sequence')
                ->where('prefix', 'PR.')
                ->get();

foreach($sequence as $doc){

        $sequence_id = $doc->ad_sequence_id;
        $prefix = $doc->prefix;
        $no     = $doc->currentnext;
    }

$data_array = array(
        "data" => array(
            "entityName" => "sequence",
            "organization" => "school",
            "description" => "test",
            "userContact" => $sequence_id,
            "document" => $prefix.$no
        )
    );

return $data_array;
```

$sequence results

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#298 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#300 ▼
      +"ad_sequence_id": "99231CC71F38431592CBE8E09CF0DDBF"
      +"created": "2018-02-01 12:12:05"
      +"createdby": "0"
      +"updated": "2021-10-26 10:02:03.243"
      +"updatedby": "0"
      +"name": "DocumentNo_M_Requisition"
      +"description": "Value for Table M_Requisition"
      +"startno": "10000000"
      +"currentnext": "81"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You get `sequence_id` last value since you don't declare as `array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping inside the results and declaring the $sequence_id variable inside of the loop. This will create two issues

1.if the result is empty then the loop will not run hence the variable will not exist.

2.if the loop has 5 data then $sequence_id will have only the last record. Same for other variable two.

For this i dont know the usage of why you are getting the last value only but declare the variable as null before the loop should solve it.

```
 $sequence_id = null;
 $prefix = null;
 $no     = null;

foreach($sequence as $doc){

        $sequence_id = $doc->ad_sequence_id;
        $prefix = $doc->prefix;
        $no     = $doc->currentnext;
    }
```

Comment: please show the results of $sequence .

Comment: I get the last value only because i want input that to another table, and i tried to declare the variable to null but I get an empty result. also i dont have problem getting the value when using WEB ROUTES as i mentioned in question, this problem show only when using API routes